# Understanding "as of", "as at", and "as from"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I'd appreciate your assistance in helping me particularly understand how to use the phrase "as of" properly.

What is the proper interpretation of the following sentence?

"I need you to get me all transactions as of January 23rd"

1. That I need all transactions from the beginning of time (so to speak) till January 23rd, or
2. That I need all transactions from January 23rd to now?

Would "as at" be more appropriate to express (1)?

Would "as from" be more appropriate to express (2)?

Comment: Did you look around first? Q. could be closed for lacking research effort.

Comment: Found at http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=94129 : It´s very difficult to reach a conclusion when people in the forum give their different opinions about a particular language issue and these views do not coincide. 

There seems [sic] to be different ways of using the "as of now" phrase depending on the country you are in.

So in this case the use of a dictionary could be the best way to clarify this thread.

The trouble is that I haven´t been able to find any clear source of information in dictionaries up to this time. ['load']

Answer (score 14):

Joel is mistaken when he says that **as of** means "up to and including a point of time," although it is often used to mean so.

**As of** designates the point in time from which something occurs. So **as of** some point would mean from the date specified onward.

However, his answering of the best way to say each phrase is spot on.

One may use either **until** or **up to** to mean the time before which something occurs (remaining ambiguous about whether the date is inclusive or not).

And **since** is a fine choice.

So far as **as from**--this is a perfectly good expression in English. It has roughly the same connotation as **as of** except that it often holds the time before and the time after in contrast.

Comment: No, "as of" can mean both - 1) As of today, only three survivors have been found. 2) As of today, all passengers must check their luggage before boarding the plane.

Answer (score 5):

**As OF** implies everything up to and including a particular point in time.

**As AT** is similar to *as of*, and could be used synonymously.  *As at* has a connotation of a snapshot.  You might say *transactions as of* but *balance as at*.

**As FROM** is not an idiom in English as far as I have ever heard.

In order to be more clear, you could use different language altogether:

1. I need all transactions *up to and including* January 23rd.
2. I need all transactions *since* January 23rd.

Comment: _As from_ is common in a different construction: _As from 20 March, this office will be closed on Mondays_. My mother used to inveigh against this usage, claiming that it should the _from_, and that _as from_ was appropriate only when it meant _as if from_; but I've never heard anybody else argue this.

Comment: @ColinFine - Thanks.  I personally have not encountered _as from_ used in this way and I would agree with your mother wholeheartedly.

Comment: "As at" typically means "on a particular date or time". In AmE, "as of" is often to express the same. Tenses provide the clues. E.g. "As of today, there are 10 members in the union."

Comment: According to Cambridge English dictionary 'As of' means "starting from a particular time or date". So it would be the opposite of 'as at' not the synonym.

Comment: @Daniel, read John V's comment to Ben Mullikin's answer. The context of OP's question implies backward looking use (report of actions that have occurred over a period of time) so my answer is appropriate to this context.

Answer (score 1):

AS OF would mean "at a certain time onward". 
AS AT would mean "at a precise time of event".
AS FROM would mean "at a certain time onward" just like AS OF, but I still don't quite get it.

That leads me to go back and use SINCE. Much simpler and people use it in writings and speeches. So, why not?

Answer (score 0):

You can argue that *as from* needn't exist, or that it's silly, but you can't argue that it's not an expression in use. From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as-from-or-of?q=as%20from):

> chiefly British Used to indicate the time or date from which something
>   starts:

It is most commonly used in referring to the starting date of a period at which something applies, or rather will apply, since the reference is usually to a time in the future at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a valid point. Dictionaries disagree.

This definition of **as of** is given by [Wiktionary](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/as-of):

> From, at, or until a given time.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-of) concurs:

> up to, on, or from (a specified time)

Most dictionaries give the first two senses as listed by Wikipedia, but Garner [[A Dictionary of Modern Legal Usage; Bryan A. Garner](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=35dZpfMmxqsC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=%22as+of+now%22+meaning+%22as+yet%22&source=bl&ots=karURAl8Ja&sig=aXjC3RdkhE74BZ9BklHflno3d7I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Xuo9Vd_7Oo2VatSigdAI&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22as%20of%20now%22%20meaning%20%22as%20yet%22&f=false)] disagrees:

> But *as of now* does not mean 'at present'; rather it means 'up to the
> present time'.... [It] is today totally unobjectionable in AmE.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer. It seems merely a comment agreeing with the OP on their confusion.

Comment: It is certainly an answer. There are three conflicting meanings in play, licensed by certain dictionaries. 'As of' is ill-defined. Any answer claiming that only one meaning is licensed is incorrect. // You mean 'I don't like this answer.'

Answer (score 0):

> What is the proper interpretation of the following sentence?
>
> "I need you to get me all transactions as of January 23rd"

This sentence is ambiguous:

If "as of January 23rd" is adjectival, then not only can it mean

> That I need all transactions from the beginning of time (so to speak) till January 23rd,

and

> That I need all transactions from January 23rd to now?

but if "as of January 23rd" is adverbial, it can also mean "As of January 23rd, your job will include getting me all the transactions."

**Absent context**, the grammar and construction is correct but the content is ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

As at, means any occurrence previous till a given time period, or date, whereas, as of, means any occurrence from a given time period or date onwards. The former is a destination whereas the latter is a starter. 
E.g. 
1. Uche had left office as at 5 o'clock I arrived.
2. The parties hereto, have caused this agreement to be duly executed as of 27th of April, 2015.