# How to specify a date or version to indicate that the situation might be different in the future

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

(I have huge difficulties expressing this without an example, feel free to edit everything)

I have information that refers to the current version of a software. It might be irrelevant to users of later versions. Or not, I won't update that information. So I would like to say

> Don't press 'erase' as it will erase everything
>   
> (foo version xy)

In German we have a neat way of writing that mostly used for dates but also applicable for version numbers:

> Kaffemaschine kann nur eine Tasse auf einmal füllen
>   
> (Stand 3.05.2013) <-Information might be outdated if much time has passed

Is there a common way of expressing that in English?

My best shot is 'as of dd.mm.yyyy'
But don't want to express that information is valid from now on,
I want to say that information is valid at least at that mark

Comment: I think your own suggestion (*as of version <version>* or *as of <date>*, whichever is more appropriate)  sounds good.

Comment: "Correct at time of writing", maybe?

Comment: Simply say "version 0.5".  Anyone half awake will realize they have a pre-release version that is bound to change.

Comment: I think @anotherdave's "correct at time of writing", followed by the date in brackets, would cover the bases nicely.

Answer (score 1):

### as of

I would take "The erase button will erase everything (as of version 1.2.4.1)" to mean "In version 1.2.4.1 the erase button will erase everything. In earlier versions it either didn't exist, or only erased some things.

I would take "As of January 31st, version 1.2.4.0 will no longer be supported" to mean "Version 1.2.4.0 is currently supported. From January 31st forward it won't be." Similarly "As of January 31st, version 1.2.4.0 is no longer be supported" means "We stopped supporting version 1.2.4.0 on January 31st." This meaning is backed up by [Cambridge dictionaries online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-of-from).

[Some references](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20of) contend that "as of" can also mean "up to ###", and I certainly agree that that is what it means in the example "I need you to get me all transactions as of January 23rd" (from [this question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112770/understanding-as-of-as-at-and-as-from)).

For your particular example I think there would be ambiguity as to the meaning, hence I agree with you that it's not a perfect fit for your particular situation.

### as at

In my opinion, a much better fit would be "**as at** ###", which I take to mean "at this particular point in time". I say "my opinion" because I haven't found any decent references for it, like I have for "as of".

So, *personally*, I think "as at" carries no implication of either what has come before, or what will come after. It just means "at a snapshot taken at this point in time / this version, the statement was true".

Answer (score 0):

As long as a statement applies to all versions, no clarification should be necessary. If a statement no longer applies to the current version, you could append "(foo version xy or earlier)" to it to indicate that it applies only to "foo version xy" and all previous versions.

Comment: I think the point made in the question was that even if the information applies to all versions to date, it may not apply to future versions. Ie, from what I understand @user2740 wants to date the information so that the reader has a chance of determining if it is likely to be relevant even if the document is never updated again.

Answer (score 0):

"as of mm/dd/yy" does not necessarily mean that it will still be true in the distant future. But it does imply it will be true for a short while at least.  The fact is that it will not change any sooner than the date the next version is released, whenever that might be. So it is important to emphasize the version number, whether or not you mention the date.

- (as of version x.x) Don't press Erase, as it will erase everything!
- (In ver x.x, released mm/dd/yy) Don't press Erase, as it will erase everything!

However, if that example is a real one, I as a technical writer would insist that the programmer de-activate that Erase button (or else pop up a clear and blatant warning/confirmation dialog if a user selects it) since Erase is so dangerous as to never be used.

IMHO, No software should ever allow an option that is *never* a proper user action.  (One can "write around" almost any program quirk, but I would draw the line at one like that!)

Comment: The example is made up :-) 
See bottom of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202870/diff-against-the-working-directory-with-git-latexdiff/) for the real one